# Use SOCKS5 with auth in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, google-chrome-extensions, socks-proxy, socks5

I am trying to configure Google Chrome to use my proxy. 
It works fine with `curl`:

```
curl -v --socks5-hostname bla-bla.example:1080 -U bla:bla-bla https://www.google.com/
```

I've tried to use [FoxyProxy](https://getfoxyproxy.org/), but I get `ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED`

I've also tried macOS advanced network preferences, result stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome, Internet Explorer, Edge only support SOCKS4.

Firefox supports 4, 4a and 5, but not with auth (although I understand there was a patch submitted).

If you want to use a web browser via SOCKS with auth, you could use something like Proxifier to divert the browser connections, or the AutoText SOCKS client (which supports GSSAPI authentication).

Comment: well chrome supports socks5 too but without authentication support

Comment: windows 11 made it harder to find SOCKS settings.  It looks like you only have 1 option for proxy settings now, instead of previously where you could set proxies and ports for different protocols and explicitly choose SOCKS, it now seems like Microsoft thinks that was all too hard for people so removed all choice and option.  Progress.  You have to use the legacy control panel to find the legacy version of the proxy config.  It doesn't state support for SOCKS v4 or v5, it just calls it "Socks".